# How to get Date Response headers in services worker with CORS?

Tags: javascript, cors, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to intercept response from back-end api and trying to get the date header to handle cache expiry.

**1. When date header is not available:**

Ex:
My web page hosted in abc.com
My backhand is in xyz.com

In above case i am seeing only below heads with key value

`{cache-control: "private", content-length: "xxxx", content-type: "application/json;charset=utf-8"}`

**2. When date header is available:**

If both back-end and web is hosted in same domain (ex: abc.com)

I wanted to access date header in CASE 1 above.
Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server needs to set [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) on the CORS response if you want the `Date` header to be visible to your client code.

There's more info at https://jeffy.info/2019/07/22/exposing-cors-headers.html